# Using free() can't deallocate memory

Tags: c, string, malloc, free

The function `getFree()` I have seen it in one of the answers to a similar question, but the string `cpy` still have the same string given for the 1st time for number of times it runs i.e., T times. So, someone please help.

```
void getFree(char ** ptr) {
    if (*ptr != NULL) {
        free(*ptr);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    int T, j;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (j = 0; j < T; j++) {
        char * cpy,
        int count = 0, i = 0, x = 0, k = 0;
        cpy = (char*)malloc(500 * sizeof(char));
        if (getchar() == '\n') {
            do {
                *(cpy + i) = getchar();
                i++;
            } while(*(cpy + i - 1) != '\n');
        }
        getFree(&cpy); 
        printf("%s", cpy);           
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the code doing that you don't expect?  What do you expect?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: sorry for the mess, I just want to know how can i change the string every time the for loop runs.

Comment: You do - it's a new string in the same memory. You didn't zero the memory or nul-terminate the string though. Perhaps you could show the specific behaviour you don't like?

Answer (score 5):

Free invalidates the pointer, but does not change the value. You should zero it if that is what you want. After freeing it, what it points to is undefined, but is likely to contain the last thing in it until it is reused.

```
free(*ptr);
*ptr = NULL;
```

Comment: My first response to this code was "wtf???"  Your response is much better - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider making your `getFree` a macro (as an alternative in the spirit of [Robert Jacobs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31436935/841108)), like

```
#define GET_FREE_AT_BIS(Lin,PtrVar) do { \
  void**ptr_##Lin = (void**) &(PtrVar);  \
  if (*ptr_##Lin) free (*ptr_##Lin);     \
  *ptr_##Lin = NULL;                     \
} while(0)

#define GET_FREE_AT(Lin,PtrVar) GET_FREE_AT_BIS(Lin,PtrVar)
#define GET_FREE(PtrVar) GET_FREE_AT(__LINE__,(PtrVar))
```

the double indirection is required to get `__LINE__` expanded and suitable for macro concatenation. It is used to have somehow unique variable names like `ptr_123` for a macro invocation from line 123 (to ease debugging, and often avoid clashes with variables named `ptr`)

then code

```
GET_FREE(cpy);
```

wthout any visible address-of operator (which gets done in the macro expansion).

My macro should work even if invoked as `GET_FREE(ptrarr[i++]);` but a simpler but wrong variant like

```
#define GET_FREE_BUGGY(PtrVar) do { free(PtrVar); PtrVar=NULL; } while(0)
```

won't work as people expect when invoked as `GET_FREE_BUGGY(ptrarr[i++]);` because then `i` would be incremented twice.

Comment: Note that the `if (*ptr_##Lin)` is superfluous, `free(0)` is a silent no-op. Apart from that, neat idea :)

Answer (score 0):

If `free` *didn't* deallocate memory, as you suggest, a subsequent call to `malloc` would have to return a different address. Note that the argument isn't changed, it's just undefined behaviour to access it after `free` returns.

It's only because `free` actually does deallocate memory that a subsequent call to `malloc` can (and does) return the same address when you request the same amount of memory.

And why not? This is actually optimal behaviour. If you're just concerned about the contents of the (re)allocated memory - neither `free` nor `malloc` tell you anything about what's in there. Since there are no guarantees or requirements on the contents, they decided to leave it alone.

If you want your memory zeroed, use `calloc` or `memset` or something instead. Otherwise just relax and stop making assumptions about what should be in your uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case, the string need not reallocate in every loop iteration. Consider this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char * cpy = malloc(500);    // Allocate in the beginning
    int T, i;
    scanf("%d\n", &T);    // Clear newline buffer
    while (T--) {
        // for (i = 0; (cpy[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i);    // Scan until newline
        fgets(cpy, 499, stdin);    // Scan until newline
        printf("%s", cpy);
    }
    free(cpy);    // Free in the end
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
3
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

**Output**

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
```

See a demo http://ideone.com/KKEz0j.